# Splitting A File On Delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, split

I have a file on a Linux system that is roughly 10GB. It contains 20,000,000 binary records, but each record is separated by an ASCII delimiter "$". I would like to use the split command or some combination thereof to chunk the file into smaller parts. Ideally I would be able to specify that the command should split every 1,000 records (therefore every 1,000 delimiters) into separate files. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only unorthodox part of the problem seems to be the record separator. I'm sure this is fixable in awk pretty simply - but I happen to hate `awk`.

I would transfer it in the realm of 'normal' problems first:

```
tr '$' '\n' < large_records.txt | split -l 1000
```

This will by default create `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`... files; look at [`man split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) for more options

Comment: This worked perfectly for the records it produces up until it reached an error (I assume this is a very easy fix). The error is: split: Output file suffixes exhausted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ermmm... I fixed the manpage link for you; [`split ... -a 7`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) should do nicely

Answer (score 2):

I love awk :)

```
BEGIN { RS="$"; chunk=1; count=0; size=1000 }
{
   print $0 > "/tmp/chunk" chunk; 
   if (++count>=size) {
      chunk++;
      count=0;
   }
}
```

(note that the redirection operator in awk only truncates/creates the file on its first invocation - subsequent references are treated as append operations - unlike shell redirection)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure by default the unix split will exhaust with suffixes once it reaches max threshold of default suffix limit of 2. More info on : https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html